# Magento switch Grand Total (Excl.Tax) and Grand Total (Incl.Tax) in totals table

Tags: php, mysql, magento

i have a question about switching the positions of Grand Total (Incl.Tax) and Grand Total (Incl.Tax) which are listed in the totals table.  I mean the totals table in my sale emails. The Grand Total (Excl.Tax) is in the middle of the totals table and the position of Grand Total (Incl.Tax) is on the bottom. I use Magento ver. 1.9.2.1.

I found out that the totals are rendered in this code snippet.

```
<?php foreach ($this->getTotals() as $_code => $_total): ?>
      <?php if ($_total->getBlockName()): ?>
          <?php echo $this->getChildHtml($_total->getBlockName(), false); ?>
      <?php else:?>
      <tr class="<?php echo $_code?>">       
          <td <?php echo $this->getLabelProperties()?>>
              <?php if ($_total->getStrong()):?>
              <strong><?php echo $this->escapeHtml($_total->getLabel());?></strong>
              <?php else:?>
              <?php echo $this->escapeHtml($_total->getLabel());?>
              <?php endif?>
          </td>
          <td <?php echo $this->getValueProperties()?>>
              <?php if ($_total->getStrong()):?>
              <strong><?php echo $this->formatValue($_total) ?></strong>
              <?php else:?>
              <?php echo $this->formatValue($_total) ?>
              <?php endif?>
          </td>
      </tr>
      <?php endif?>
  <?php endforeach ?>
```

But i can't find the something like an order for the positions or something like this. I found some tutorials in the internet but nothing really works.

**Update:**

I can solve the problem by changing the method in Tax.php (/app/code/local/Mage/Tax/Block/Sales/Order/Tax.php):

```
protected function _initGrandTotal()
    {
        $store  = $this->getStore();
        $parent = $this->getParentBlock();
        $grandototal = $parent->getTotal('grand_total');
        if (!$grandototal || !(float)$this->_source->getGrandTotal()) {
            return $this;
        }

        if ($this->_config->displaySalesTaxWithGrandTotal($store)) {
            $grandtotal         = $this->_source->getGrandTotal();
            $baseGrandtotal     = $this->_source->getBaseGrandTotal();
            $grandtotalExcl     = $grandtotal - $this->_source->getTaxAmount();
            $baseGrandtotalExcl = $baseGrandtotal - $this->_source->getBaseTaxAmount();
            $grandtotalExcl     = max($grandtotalExcl, 0);
            $baseGrandtotalExcl = max($baseGrandtotalExcl, 0);
            $totalExcl = new Varien_Object(array(
                'code'      => 'grand_total',
                'strong'    => false,
                'value'     => $grandtotalExcl,
                'base_value'=> $baseGrandtotalExcl,
                'label'     => $this->__('Grand Total (Excl.Tax)')
            ));
            $totalIncl = new Varien_Object(array(
                'code'      => 'grand_total_incl',
                'strong'    => true,
                'value'     => $grandtotal,
                'base_value'=> $baseGrandtotal,
                'label'     => $this->__('Grand Total (Incl.Tax)')
            ));
            $parent->addTotal($totalIncl, 'tax');
            $parent->addTotal($totalExcl, 'grand_total');
            $this->_addTax('grand_total');

        }
        return $this;
    }
```